# I can't seem to get this function to add the list together

Tags: python, function, sum

I'm trying to find a way to add up a list of numbers without using the sum function. I'm a little new to this and so far this is what I've got:

```
def findSum(nbr_list):
    total = 0
    nbr_list = []
    for nbr in nbr_list:
        total = total + nbr
    print 'Total: ', total

In [32]: nbr_list = [1,2,3,4,100]

In [33]: findSum(nbr_list)
Total:  0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining `nbr_list` on this line:

```
nbr_list = []
```

Doing this causes `nbr_list` to no longer refer to the `[1,2,3,4,100]` list that you passed into the function but rather the empty list `[]`.  This means that the for-loop will be iterating over an empty list and `total` will never be incremented.  Thus, `0` is printed because that is the initial value of `total`.

Simply removing that line makes your function work fine:

```
>>> def findSum(nbr_list):
...     total = 0
...     for nbr in nbr_list:
...         total += nbr  # Same as 'total = total + nbr'
...     print 'Total: ', total
...
>>> nbr_list = [1,2,3,4,100]
>>> findSum(nbr_list)
Total:  110
>>>
```

Also, you usually do not want to make your functions print a value and not return anything.  A better approach would be to have `findSum` return `total` and then print the result of calling the function:

```
def findSum(nbr_list):
    total = 0
    for nbr in nbr_list:
        total += nbr
    return total

nbr_list = [1,2,3,4,100]
print 'Total: ', findSum(nbr_list)
```